# increase the value of x by 1

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, increment

```
    x=1
    if display == old_display:
      x=x+1
      print(x)
      print(stages[7-x])
```

I need the value of `x` to increase by 1 when the condition display == old display is true

I tried to set the condition with if statement and when it is true i need x to decrease by 1. This is a part of hang man game and this part of code is to display the hang man structure when choosing wrong letter.

Comment: Nothing after `continue` will be executed.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your posted code. And note that `range` can accept start, stop, step parameters so no need for you to manually increment or decrement the loop variable.

Comment: You can't decrease the variable that's being used in `for x in range(6):`, it will always go from 0 to 5. Use a different variable for the loop.

Comment: As already said this code makes little sense. The only thing that gets executed is `continue`. Don't you miss `else:` or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if display == old_display:
    x -=1
```

this snippet decreases `x` by 1 every time `display == old_display`